# How to Make X% + X% Discount in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, discount

Is it possible to make X% + X% discount in Magento? If yes, then how to achieve that.

Example: 5 + 5 off if the Cart Value is above 100 USD

Comment: provide more information about your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the best way to do this is to create TWO shopping cart price rules (or catalog price rules) that will be applied in sequential order.

The first rule would be a 5% discount if subtotal > $100, bringing the subtotal to $95.

The second rule would be a 5% discount if subtotal > $95 (because you have to account for the first discount).

Alternatively, you could create a "compiled rule" for $5 off of $100 + $5 off of $95 = $90.25; the computed discount is 9.75%.

Please note that without a lot of manipulation, you can only add in a cart price rule based on the sub-total (vs. grand total), because the grand total needs inputs such as shipping and tax.  While there are ways to do this from the grand total, you risk creating an infinite loop in the logic and having the site fail.

I hope this helps!